# How to identify the which button clicked on which section UICollectionView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` and it has 2 sections. Each section header has a button. I tried to send the section id to an another view controller on `prepareForSegue` like following.

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ManualCapture"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];

    ManualCapture *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.sectionId = indexPath.section;
}
```

but it sends `0` as the section id. Is there any possible way to gets the section id ? How can I send the sectionId according to the button click. Basically I want to do, When I clicked the button in section 1, on `prepareForSegue` it should be sent 0, If I clicked the button in section 2, on `prepareForSegue` it should be sent 1. How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is `sender` really the cell or is actually the button? It needs to be the cell for `indexPathForCell:` to work.

Comment: actually a button. So how can I do this?

Comment: If you pass something other than a proper cell to `indexPathForCell:`, the resulting `indexPath` will be `nil` which is why you get 0 for the section.

Comment: is there any possible way to pass the section id to another view?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579911/indexpath-of-the-button-from-uicollectionview

Comment: If we  want the section on from which button is clicked ,we can assign tag to the button . @rmaddy: is it good way to do ?

Comment: `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[self.collectionView convertPoint:sender.center fromView:sender.superview]];`
but index path is `nil`

Comment: Sorry, just realized that will only work for a button in a cell, not a section header. Using the button's tag can work as long as sections are fixed.

Comment: http://www.raizlabs.com/2013/10/animating_items_uicollectionview/

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did it using tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:
in collection view delegate method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *tagStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
yourButton.tag = [tagStr intValue];
}
```

then when you want to check for which section or index it is access it by its tag, like this:

```
UIButton *temp = (UIButton *)sender;
NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",temp.tag];
```

then compare it.